# iAd banner is loaded but still get an error

Tags: objective-c, iad

I added an iAd banner to my app. If I run the app on my device the banner apperars but I still get errors:

```
2014-07-29 21:00:55.729 Tipps & Tricks[15639:60b] Cannot find executable for    CFBundle 0x10c185010   </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MusicLibrary.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-07-29 21:00:55.732 Tipps & Tricks[15639:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x10c18e4b0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-07-29 21:00:55.769 Tipps & Tricks[15639:60b] Cannot find executable for  CFBundle 0x10c24da10 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GeoServices.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-07-29 21:00:55.779 Tipps & Tricks[15639:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x10c2653b0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/iAdFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-07-29 21:00:56.393 Tipps & Tricks[15639:60b] [AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this banner" UserInfo=0x10d81ffb0 {ADInternalErrorCode=7, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad was unloaded from this banner, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain}
2014-07-29 21:00:58.794 Tipps & Tricks[15639:60b] [AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x112734b30 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain}
2014-07-29 21:00:59.794 Tipps & Tricks[15639:60b] [AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content" UserInfo=0x112734ae0 {ADInternalErrorCode=5, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Banner view is visible but does not have content, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain}
```

Code Update:

.h File (TableViewController):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface UITableViewController (UITableViewController) <ADBannerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *iAD;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL canDisplayBannerAds;

@end
```

.m File (TableViewController):

```
#import "UITableViewController+UITableViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>


@implementation UITableViewController (UITableViewController)
@dynamic iAD;

#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

[banner setAlpha:1];

[UIView commitAnimations];

NSLog(@"iAd loaded");
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

[banner setAlpha:0];

[UIView commitAnimations];

NSLog(@"iAd donesn't loaded");

self.iAD.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{

self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
self.iAD.delegate = self;

}
```

Error:

```
2014-08-03 11:37:28.740 Tipps & Tricks[40189:1303] WARNING: Slow defaults access for     key ClientState took 0.066971 seconds, tolerance is 0.020000
2014-08-03 11:37:35.068 Tipps & Tricks[40189:60b] [AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this banner" UserInfo=0xba60df0 {ADInternalErrorCode=7, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad was unloaded from this banner}
2014-08-03 11:38:51.973 Tipps & Tricks[40189:60b] [AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this banner" UserInfo=0xb89d280 {ADInternalErrorCode=7, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad was unloaded from this banner}
```

Does somebody knows what I could do?

Comment: Have you implemented the delegate methods and set the delegate of your banner view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tell yo your class that using iAD `<ADBannerViewDelegate>`?

Then in ViewDidLoad write:

```
self.banner.delegate = self;
```

As said  above, implement delegate methods of ADBannerView also:

```
didFailToReceiveAdWithError
```

Comment: I added the `self.banner.delegate = self;` line in the viewDidLoad method. And now I didn't get the first error but an other error comes up and I don't know why because I haven't a banner in my tableviewcontroller. `2014-08-01 22:34:55.991 Tipps & Tricks[32930:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController iAD]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c04a230'` I just added this method in my .h file of the tableView Class: `@property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *iAD;`

Comment: please show here your code in your question(just update your question with code).

Comment: did you link your iAD Object in interface builder?

Comment: You should create IBOutlet

Comment: I can't create an IBOutlet because I have no physical added iAd banner in the storyboard.

Comment: That's it, You have added an object from interface builder in your Storyboard. So you should create IBOutlet

Comment: I've done it. But it's still not working. I added the same code in a viewController File and it's working. If I run the app without `property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *iAD;` the banner comes up in the tableViewController.

Comment: I added the errors in the question, if I run the app without `property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *iAD;`.

Comment: first don't call your category like UITableViewController+ UITableViewController. What's this @dynamic iAD? make synthesise or use iVars.

Comment: `@synthesize`isn't allowed in a categories implementation.

Comment: this comes up if I delete `@dynamic iAD;`: `Property 'iAD' requires method 'iAD' to be defined - use @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this category`

Comment: anyway your method accepting parameter banner and you are sending iAD. After { set banner  = iAD. And you don't have to make category for this. Make logical name for category. for example iAD+UIViewController

Comment: Because I'm new in developing iOS Apps I don't understand all. Can you please say me what I have to write in which method (your 1st & 2nd sentence). I use a category because I added also an alertView and not just the iAd banner in the TableView. I changed also the name of it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you named the method -(void)bannerView:

```
//in the storyboard, the delegate is set to ViewController

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate>
@end

@interface ViewController() 
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ADBannerView *adBanner;
@end

@implementation View Controller
- (void)viewDidLoad {
self.adBanner.delegate = self;
}
//this is the working method; note the method name
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"banner failed to receive ad with error:%@", error);
    if (self.bannerIsVisible) {
        [self hidesBanner];
    }
}
//this is the non working method; not the method name
//this will never fire because Apples method name is different
- (void)adBannerView:(ADBannerView *)adBanner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"banner failed to receive ad with error:%@", error);
    if (self.bannerIsVisible) {
        [self hidesBanner];
    }
}
```